# Set Origin shortcut not working?

Tags: shortcut, origin

The shortcut for Set Origin (Shift + Ctrl + Alt + c) isn't working.

When I searched for the action in the search bar accessed by pressing <kbd>f3</kbd> there were no buttons noted after the "Set origin" action, which is weird.

I don't know why and how this happened. How do i fix this?

Comment: In Blender 2.8 there isn't a shortcut assigned for this operation in the default keymap.

Comment: Robert is right, you can get the menu only through *Right click*, or *Object > Set Origin* since 2.8.

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, the shortcut <kbd>Shift-Ctr-Alt-C</kbd> has been deprecated in the latest version(s) of Blender: Blender 2.8. The only way to access the Set Origin command as of now is to either through *Object > Set Origin*, [image: How to set object origin way #1]

or via the right-click/<kbd>W</kbd> key menu (depending on your keymap; refer below).

Of course, you *could* just switch to the old Blender 2.7x keymap via the `Keymap` section in the Blender Preferences, which would allow you to use the <kbd>Shift-Ctr-Alt-C</kbd> shortcut,

[image: How to change the default keymap layout for Blender]

although I highly doubt that the devs would consider updating it with every new release of Blender, so it would be recommended to just use the first two methods.

**EDIT**:

I understand your query to its full extent now. The behaviour that Blender does not offer the menu for the keyframing action along with the suggestion in the search-bar menu is not a bug; it is supposed to happen (it will pop-up once you click on the "suggestion"). However, if you still feel that it *is* indeed a bug, feel free to report it to the [Blender Open Report Bug Tracker](https://developer.blender.org/maniphest/).

Answer (score 2):

If you don't mind using pie menus, you can enable the shipped [Pie Menus](https://docs.blender.org/manual/fr/dev/addons/interface/viewport_pies.html) add-on. There's an 'Origins' pie available through that. Default shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>X</kbd>. It can also send the origin straight to your selection starting in Edit Mode, skipping a step.

Answer (score 0):

*Preferences > Keymap > 3D View > Object Non-modal > Add New*.

Expand *None* and type in active field `object.origin_set` set shortcut to <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> Done!